# Not Defining Second Method?

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming, null, ruby-1.9

I want this code to define two methods, `nilguard` and `falseguard`, which guard against nil and false values.

```
Object.class_eval do
  @list = [false, nil]
  @list.each do |i|
    define_method :"#{i}guard" do |other|
      if self == i
        return other
      else
        return self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, it only defines `falseguard`, which works fine. Why is this, why isn't it defining the other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil.to_s == ''`, so your second method will just be called `guard`. You might want to use something like this instead:

```
@list = { false: false, nil: nil }
@list.each do |s, i|
  define_method "#{s}guard" do |other|
  # ...
```